# How can ViewParent be cast into View?

Tags: java, android, view, android-view

This code:

```java
(View) contentView.getParent();
```

I don't quite get it: ViewParent is an interface, View is a class that doesn't implement that interface.

How do they transform into one another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works in most cases because most `ViewParent`s are [`ViewGroup`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup)s.

`ViewGroup` extends `View` and implements `ViewParent`, so it satisfies both.

The reason that `ViewParent` is a separate interface is that this won't *always* work: if you keep going up the tree, you'll eventually find a `ViewParent` that is not a `ViewGroup` (specifically, you'll get to the [`ViewRootImpl`](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/0df17739ade086abf5a1a75c33082350f5074b1a:frameworks/base/core/java/android/view/ViewRootImpl.java;l=146)), and thus also not a `View`, and that will result in a `ClassCastException`.

Comment: It's also interesting that by accessing the inferface you actually accessing the the whole class that inplements the interface,I guess that is just the way it is.

Comment: Well, that's what the cast is for: just accessing the interface along doesn't get you the whole class.  You have to be explicit that you know that it's _actually_ an object of that class, and you're willing to accept an Exception if that's not the case.